# Static Freemarker Templates

Tags: templates, static, mocking, frontend, freemarker

I'm a front-end developer, I've been dropped into a Java team that is using Spring MVC, Maven, DropWizzard, etc with Freemarker (FTL) templates for rendering views.

I'd love to be able to work with the Freemarker templates without needing to do any of the normal compilation WAR/JAR files, etc each time I do a change.

I want to essentially decouple the FTL templates but make them still directly consumable. I'd provide dummy/mock data when I'm working with them but when used in the app they'd pull in the real data.

Has anybody done this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with DropWizard, but usually, you can run Web applications directly from the IDE (like Eclipse), without explicitly compiling and packing them. Otherwise the developers would pull their hair out too. This can also mean that you can edit the templates without even restarting the application. FreeMarker itself is capable of detecting template changes and reloading them, though it depends on the setup if it will actually work. (One related FreeMarker setting is `template_update_delay`, which should be set to 0 or some low value.)

Also, FreeMarker can be configured to load templates from an external directory, though yet again I'm not sure how to achieve that with DropWizard. It seems that you can set arbitrary FreeMarker settings under `views`/`.ftl` in the `yml` file (as seen on http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/docs/manual/views.html), and so could do something like `template_loader: freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader(java.io.File('/my/templates'))` too, but maybe DropWizard overwrites the template loader with its own...

But you say you also want to provide mock data. So perhaps you don't want to use that DropWizard application at all. For a developer it's quite easy to drop together an app where you can visit a template loaded from an external directory, and some Groovy scripts that set up the mock data-model that's also in an external directory... something like that, but I don't know of such utility. (The closest is perhaps FMPP.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It has put the developers and myself along the right track.